# SpringBootTest classes attribute not loading configuration class

Tags: spring, spring-boot

After updating from Spring Boot 1.4 to 2.1.1, I have an issue which seems to be that my `SpringBootTest` is no longer loading the test configuration class.
 Here are the ways I have tried and the class is not getting loaded. Any package that the config class component scans or any bean created in the config class are not there. I have tried these approaches which worked in Spring Boot 1.4.x but no longer work in 2.1.1:-

```
@SpringBootTest(classes=TestConfig.class)
```

or like this

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes=TestConfig.class)
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Which is to say, please post the code of your unit test.

Comment: I can't figure out how to use this site its a pita. How do you post code snippets

Comment: It's a markdown variant. Click edit, paste your code, select it, Ctrl+K will format it.

Comment: Thanks Roddy for the info on how to format.

Comment: If you get it to work, you should post an answer. The Q&A format supports and encourages answering your own question if you figure it out yourself. But post it as an *answer* and not an edit to your existing question or a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestConfig.class)
```